# test class getting null values for path and query

Tags: java, jpa, junit, mockito, hibernate-entitymanager

I am trying to test createQuery db call but getting null pointer exception

```
 @Override
    public Member fetchMemberByNetworkId(String networkId) {
        List<Member> memberList = new ArrayList<Member>();
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Member> c = cb.createQuery(Member.class);
        Root<Member> root = c.from(Member.class);
        Expression<String> path = root.get("networkid");
        Expression<String> upper =cb.upper(path);
        Predicate cp = cb.equal(upper, networkId.toUpperCase());
        c.where(cb.and(cp));
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(c);

           memberList = query.getResultList();


        //List<Member> memberList = query.getResultList();


        if(null != memberList && CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(memberList)) {
            return memberList.get(0);
        }
        else{
            return new Member() ;
        }
    }




 public class ExperimentBeanTransformerTest {

    //~ Instance fields ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    ExperimentBeanTransformer experimentBeanTransformer = new ExperimentBeanTransformer();
    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    UserGroupManagementService memberService = new UserGroupManagementServiceImplementation();

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    UserGroupManagementDAO userGroupManagementDAO = new UserGroupManagementDAOImplementation();


    @Mock
    transient  EntityManager entityManager ;
    @Mock
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder ;
    @Mock
    CriteriaQuery<Member> criteriaQuery;
    @Mock
    Root<Member> root;
    @Mock
    Expression expr;
    @Mock
    Path path;
    @Mock
    Predicate predicate;

    transient Query query = mock(Query.class);
    @Mock
    TypedQuery<Member> querymem;


    //~ Methods --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
  @Test
    public void testfecthFullNameOfUser() {
        String networkId = "network";
        List<Member> members = buildMembersList(5);
        String queryname="Experiment.findCount";
       final List<Member> members2 = new ArrayList<Member>(buildMembersList(5));
        Expression<String> doublePath = root.get(networkId);
        when(entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()).thenReturn(criteriaBuilder);
        when(criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Member.class)).thenReturn(criteriaQuery);
        when(criteriaQuery.from(Member.class)).thenReturn(root);
        when(root.get((networkId))).thenReturn(doublePath);
        when(criteriaBuilder.upper(root.<String>get("networkid"))).thenReturn(expr);
        when(criteriaBuilder.equal(expr, networkId.toUpperCase())).thenReturn(predicate);

        when(entityManager.createQuery((String) any())).thenReturn( querymem);


        when(query.getResultList()).thenReturn(members2);
        when(memberService.fetchMemberByNetworkId(networkId)).thenReturn(members);
        when(userGroupManagementDAO.fetchMemberByNetworkId(networkId)).thenReturn((Member) members);

        experimentBeanTransformer.fecthFullNameOfUser(networkId);


    }
```

I am getting query, path null values.  Do I have to instantiate Path, I tried but not able to assign value to it? How to test mock path `(root.get())`?

Answer (score 0):

In fetchMemberByNetworkId(String networkId) method, you have hardcoded root.get() method call with string literal "networkid".

> Expression path = root.get("networkid");

But Your test method is mocked with

```
String networkId = "network";
when(root.get((networkId))).thenReturn(doublePath);
```

In your implementation code, while calling root.get method, pass actual String argument networkId instead of string literal 'networkid'

```
public Member fetchMemberByNetworkId(String networkId) {
    // Change as below
    Expression<String> path = root.get(networkId);
```

**Observation :**
In your test code, you have assigned networkId with one value and mocking objects with different values.

> String networkId = "network";
>
> // Please check the below mock statements.

```
 when(root.get((networkId))).thenReturn(doublePath);
 when(criteriaBuilder.upper(root.<String>get("networkid"))).thenReturn(expr);
```